# Kubernetes Istio Proxying to HTTPS backend with self signed certificate

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have a pod which is only listening on HTTPS within kubernetes using a self signed certificate from a third party vendor. I am using Istio Gateway to terminate TLS for my own domain. How can I allow Istio to then proxy the request to the HTTPs backend service while ignoring the invalid certificate errors and maintain the green tick within the users browser?

Expect TLS to be terminated at the Istio gateway as normal, Istio should then proxy the request to the backend HTTPs service ignoring certificate related errors.

Comment: you have HTTPS backend but want to TLS terminate at istio level ?